# How to get around blocking issues with rendering 1000+ THREEJS sprite labels

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have close to 1000 (and at some point more) text sprite labels being rendered in a THREEJS scene. Creating the sprite objects is not an issue. When I go to add them to the scene it seems this is blocking and killing any other animations or user interactions that take place.

I have tried splitting the array of sprites into chunks and do a chunk at a time. Recently I have tried using setTimeout but am not having much luck. I am struggling with callbacks and setTimeout.
Here is what I have so far:

```
function addlabels(data){
label_array = [];
    $.each(data.nodes, function (key, value) {
        var position = value.pos;
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(position[0], position[1], position[2]);
        value.label = makeTextSprite(key, {fontsize:32});
        value.label.position.copy(vector);
        label_array.push(value.label);
    });

    function chunk_labels(items, process, context){
        var todo = items.concat();
        setTimeout(function(){
            do {
                console.log(context, todo.shift());
                scene.add(todo.shift());
            } while(todo.length > 0);
            if (todo.length > 0){
                setTimeout(chunk_labels(todo), 25);
            }else{
                callback(items);
            }
        }, 25);
    }

    chunk_labels(label_array);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this addlabel function every frame? Because it looks like a very slow function to me.  Making new vec3s, making new Text Sprites, calling O(n) .shift method (n) times, setTimeout so you make the cpu go to sleep, etc.

Comment: The addlabels function is called once.  Then the creation of the labels takes place. When the labels are added to the scene is when it slows down.